# How to attach debugger to a C program when run using Jenkins

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, batch-file, jenkins

I have a batch script that calls a bunch of programs written in C that do a lot of data processing.  It works fine when run manually but when Jenkins calls the batch, one of the programs fails with a useless error message.

Before I litter the program with printf()s, I tried to use DebugBreak() to attach the debugger to see what difference Jenkins is making but the program just ends without invoking the debugger.

Is there a way to invoke the debugger from within the failing program that'll work with Jenkins?

EDIT: I tried calling MessageBox() but nothing appears and Jenkins sits there waiting for console output.

Comment: Have you tried using MessageBox("Good Place", "Attach Debugger", MB_OK).  This should cause a message box to pop up.  You can then attach the debugger then click OK.

Comment: Are you sure that the error message is useless? :)